# RegEx - More Efficient Way of removing Specific Patterns such as Prefixes and Suffixes

Tags: regex

I have a dataset that has three different types of patterns in strings

**p__OP3(100)**

**c__Verruco-5**

**unclassified**

The goal is to write a RegEx that would drop the Prefix where available aka c__ and p__ along with any [] and anything parenthesis and what's inside it (100), (77)

I came up with 
    `^\w\_\_\[|\W\([^)]*\)|\([^)]*\)|^\w\_\_`

Expected output:

**OP3**

**Verruco-5**

**unclassified**

However this seems very inefficient, is there a more efficient way of writing this?

Comment: What is the expected output for the example strings?

Comment: Try `^\w__\[?|\W?\([^)]*\)`

Comment: Or try `^\w__|[][]|\([^)]*\)` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWYPTO/1)

Comment: @Thefourthbird Interesting. I wouldn't have expected `[][]` to work that way.

Comment: @Gary On [this page](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) it states that this does not work for Javascript and Ruby. `require closing brackets to be escaped with a backslash to include them as literals in a character class`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this part only once `^\w\_\_` and create a character class to match either a closing or opening square bracket.
Not that you don't have to escape the underscore to match it literally.

You might use 3 alternations to match either the prefix with the double underscore, an opening or closing square bracket or parenthesis and what is inside it:

`^\w__|[\][]|\([^)]*\)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lMHJl8/1)

Then you could replace those matches with an empty string.

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `\w__` Match word character followed by 2 times an underscore
- `|` Or
- `[\][]` Match a closing or opening square bracket
- `|` Or
- `\([^)]*\)` match opening and closing parenthesis with what is inside it using a negated character class. If you also want to match an optional non word character, then you prepend `\W?` before the opening parenthesis like `\W?\([^)]*\)`